# proving $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+\cdots+$ Without Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

i proved that:

$$
\begin{align}
& {} \quad \frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 2n} \\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\text{ for }n\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
$$

by induction.
i wonder if it can be done without using induction. if so, i'll appreciate if someone could show how.
thanks.

Comment: Sums like this can't even be defined without induction. It is possible to show this using an argument that hides induction, but induction is always implicitly present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{As }\frac1{(2r-1)2r}=\frac{2r-(2r-1)}{(2r-1)2r}=\frac1{2r-1}-\frac1{2r},$$

$$\text{we can write }\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 2n}$$

$$=\left(\frac11-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\right)$$

$$=\left(\frac11+\frac12-2\cdot\frac12\right)+\left(\frac13+\frac14-2\cdot\frac14\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}-2\cdot\frac1{2n}\right)$$

$$=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}+\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}-2\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{2n}\right)$$

$$=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}+\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}-\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\right)$$

$$=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}$$

Comment: didn't get row's 3 and 6.

Comment: @bori12, please have  a look into the edited answer

Comment: that's great, i got it! thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}=\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{k}$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let it be true for n

Then for $n+1$ we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+...+\frac{1}{(2n+1)\cdot 2(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 2n})+\frac{1}{(2n+1)\cdot 2(n+1)}$(Using induction hypothesis for $n$)

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)\cdot 2(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)\cdot 2(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac{4n+3}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac{4n+2}{(2n+1)2(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$

Comment: thanks but i asked without induction...

Comment: oops.... i had missed out the word without!!!!

Comment: sorry for that:(